# What schema.org markup for a Guitar Chord?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data, music

I'm looking for the best way to add structured data to a page that shows how to play a chord on the guitar, [like this one](https://www.fachords.com/guitar-chords/Cmaj-guitar-chord-chart/).

I think that the best schema would be `SheetMusic`, that is a direct child of `CreativeWork`. The descriptions says "Printed music, as opposed to performed or recorded music.", but it's just a proposal to be integrated into Schema.org for now.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HowTo schema](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/how-to).

“How-to” snippets aim to provide step-by-step instructions directly in the SERPs for instruction-based queries.

But before adding this schema, you need to add these instructions on your page.

Example -

> Step 1 - C Major Chord (Open Position)
>
> Step 2 - C Major Chord (based on A major shape)
>
> Step 3 - C Major Chord (based on G major shape)
>
> Step 4 - C Major Chord (based on E major shape)
>
> Step 5 - C Major Chord (based on D major shape)
>
> (Source - [liveabout.com](https://www.liveabout.com/c-major-guitar-chord-1712134))

After adding these steps, schema for these steps will be like -

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "HowTo",
  "name": "Learn the C maj guitar chord",
  "step":[
  {
    "@type": "HowToStep",
    "text": "C Major Chord (Open Position)",
    "image": "https://example.com/1x1/photo.jpg"
  }, {
    "@type": "HowToStep",
    "text": "C Major Chord (based on A major shape)",
    "image": "https://example.com/1x1/photo.jpg"
  }, {
    "@type": "HowToStep",
    "text": "C Major Chord (based on G major shape)",
    "image": "https://example.com/1x1/photo.jpg"
  }, {
    "@type": "HowToStep",
    "text": "C Major Chord (based on E major shape)",
    "image": "https://example.com/1x1/photo.jpg"
  }, {
    "@type": "HowToStep",
    "text": "C Major Chord (based on D major shape)",
    "image": "https://example.com/1x1/photo.jpg"
  }
]
}
</script>
```

Modify the schema according to your steps.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [creative work schema](https://schema.org/CreativeWork).

Comment: A link only answer is not high quality.  A better answer would explain more and give examples.   Links should be used for reference.  They are not answers in and of themselves.